# Call Method in MultiThreading

Tags: c#, multithreading

I need to call a method multiple time, Using thread.

For Example :

**Method:**

```
   private void add(int a, int b)
        {
            Console.WriteLine(a + b);
        }
```

**Call**

```
private void call()
        {
            for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++)
            {
                add(i, 2);
            }
        }
```

**above is just a example** Like this i need to call add() method in Multithread with different parameter.

Comment: You can use TPL library : System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.For(0, 10, (i) => Console.WriteLine(i));

Comment: Can you please tell me..How do we use System.Threading.Tasks.Parallel.ForEach()

Comment: TPL library using ForEach() : Parallel.ForEach<int>(Enumerable.Range(0, 10), (i) => Console.WriteLine(i));

Answer (score 0):

You can use TPL:

```
private void call()
{
    Parallel.For(0, 10, i => add(i, 2));        
}
```